# Phonenumber identification add tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, phone-number

Im trying to make a script that identify phonenumbers in Norway, basicly the format is based on 8 digits numbers but should also allow 5 digits numbers as well as 110,112,113 (which is the emergancy numbers in norway). The script beneeth does this quite perfectly, but does also affect urls and ids that match exeption. Ive tried in various ways to make this only affect inside tags (not correct tha tags itself).

```
var regex = /((\d){5})|(110)|(113)|(112)|(\d{2}(?: ?\d){6})/g; //\>+.
text = $("article:first").html().replace(regex, "<a href=\"tel:\" class='phoneme'>$&</a>");
$("article:first").html(text);
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to do this?

UPDATE:

I'll specify my problem a bit more: The point of the function is to replace all phonenumbers, given in text, with links. The reason that I use HTML is to keep alle the html inside the article tag- though I dont want to the attributes inside the tags to be affected.

Se fiddle as example

http://jsfiddle.net/LFceL/

Comment: If you only want the text to be replaced, why are you using `.html()`?

Comment: Hi, I'll specify my problem a bit more:

Comment: See update with fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by creating following function. Not really what i wanted, but it works like a glow :)

```
var runPhones = function(elm) {

    var regex = /((\d){5})|(110)|(113)|(112)|(\d{2}(?: ?\d){6})/g; 
    $("article:first *").contents().filter(function(i,e){ // Filter away all tags
        if(e.nodeType !== 1){
             e.nodeValue = e.nodeValue.replace(regex, "TEL$&TELEND")// Creating markup in text
        }
    });

    var text = $("article:first").html().replace(/TELEND/g,"</a>"); // Changeing markup to HTML
    text = text.replace(/TEL/g,"<a href='tel:' class='phoneme'>") // Changing markup to HTML

    $("article:first").html(text);

} 
runPhones();
```

I might have done this unnessesary complex, but I diddent find any way to directly parse HTML in the nodeValue.replace.

SE fiddle for demo

http://jsfiddle.net/LFceL/10/

Answer (score 0):

check following script.you can change .mask

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.maskedinput/1.3.1/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($)
                { 
                $.mask.definitions['~']='[+-]';    
                $('#W2TxtCell').mask('(999)(99999)');       
                });


    </script>   

 <input type="" id="W2TxtCell"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mr7itsurdeveloper/2Xz8q/

Comment: awful formatting :) why is there a html tag inside the script tags? + it doesn't allow  110,112,113

Comment: the OP asks for a way to identify (find) phone numbers in a text to replace them with a link to call directly (using mobile devices) valid phone numbers have 3,5 or 8 numbers. That's what I understand...

Comment: Im not sure if what i requested is possbible with this sulotion, but if you would please care to explain i would be greatfull. See update with fiddle

Comment: Nice try! But I need this to parse through the whole article- The example is just an definition of the problems. :) Thanx anyway

Comment: ok ,you don't want this regex on links in article in whole website..let me check ..

Comment: Did you find out anything - Mr7-itsurdeveloper?

Comment: a)i tried with(:not('a')),but i m facing error in last line.you can check here http://jsfiddle.net/LFceL/6/    ....b)your article structure changing or not???e.g:now links are in different div than numbers..      if both will be in save div ..then this solution will not work....

Comment: Hi, The article setup is just an example where Ive seperated working from issue. I have an solution justing jquery, but I really want to fix this with regex :). Thanx for trying.